# Rescale Raster Band With GDAL Python Bindings

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to figure out how to rescale a raster band's pixel value using the GDAL python bindings.  I am looking to emulate the -scale switch in gdal_translate.exe; rescaling the pixel values in my raster to 0-255.

EDIT:  Some goofing around today has produced this, seems to work thus far.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy
import math

def singleBandToRGB(source,output):
    src_ds = gdal.Open(source)
    band = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    min = band.GetMinimum()
    max = band.GetMaximum()
    data = src_ds.ReadAsArray(0,0,src_ds.RasterXSize,src_ds.RasterYSize)
    data = ((255-0)*((data-min)/(max-min)))+0
    data = data.astype(numpy.uint8)
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    dst_ds = driver.Create(output,src_ds.RasterXSize,src_ds.RasterYSize,3,gdal.GDT_Byte)
    for i in range(1,4):
        dst_ds.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray(data)
        dst_ds.GetRasterBand(i).ComputeStatistics(False)
    dst_ds.SetProjection(src_ds.GetProjection())
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(src_ds.GetGeoTransform())

    # housekeeping
    driver = None
    dst_ds = None
    src_ds = None
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure there's a ready-made function/class in GDAL python bindings, but if you're brave, you can look at the source of gdal_translate and find out how its done.  From my quick skim, I *think* that scale ratio is set on VRTComplexSource (dfScaleRatio property).

Comment: Could you set the scale using a GDAL Virtual Format and then open that in python?